# I would like to control enable user in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

My user class has got an 'enable' attribute. It provides if the user email has been validated. It can be true or false. However, I would like to deny this user all API functions after log in if it's not validated. I think It's not good idea check all API function one by one. I guess the firewall symfony is able to control this kind of issues, but I just see access control by checking 'roles' but nothing else.

Comment: Sorry, but I thought it was enought because the issue doesn't need more information. I'll try to be more clear the nex time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can try something like this (I assume that your API path begins with `api` prefix):

```
security:
    ...
    access_control:
        -
            path: ^/api
            allow_if: "'anon' != user and user.getEnabled() == true"
```

Comment: it works perfectly !! but now I'd like to redirect my deny user to some .html, now the default page is the login, where can I set up this issue.

Comment: @user3690919 Symfony redirects users to login page when the authentication process fails, it's configured in security.yml file under firewall section. But in your case you can try to create a listener which listens the kernel events (I don't which one, I haven't tried yet).. I think this can be a different question..

Comment: @user3690919 I created a gist which forces the users log out on certain situations, you can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/xurshid29/dcc98e071edcda518164)

Comment: Many thanks for the support, I'm going to try it. I keep you posted

Comment: I don't understand that function :(... is there another way to redirect these users? I mean the unabled users. I dont mind if the rest of the deny users (the other authentifications process) go to the login page. But I need to show the unabled users a special .html to inform them. Many thanks